# Review my browser reward plugin

Tags: javascript, plugin

I've never put together a plugin before but I thought this would be useful to push technology forward. It's basically a browser sniffer, but if the user has a modern browser it will reward them for keeping it up to date.

Unfortunately, the code is a little heavier than I expected (6kb minified).

I just wondered if anyone could give some advice on how to make it more clean and compressed.

```
function abiejs(d) {
"use strict";
/*
    abiejs.d === defaults
    abiejs.b === document body
    abiejs.c === abie container
    abiejs.e === abie experience
*/
abiejs.d = (function() {
    var def = d;
    if(!def.position){def.position = 'tr';}
    if(!def.merit){def.merit = 'http://browsehappy.com/';}
    if(!def.demerit){def.demerit = 'http://browsehappy.com/';}
    if(!def.showTime){def.showTime = 5000;}
    if(!def.content){def.content = '';}
    if(!def.meritColor){def.meritColor = 'green';}
    if(!def.demeritColor){def.demeritColor = 'red';}
    if(def.cookie){def.cookie = true;} else {def.cookie = false;}
    if(!def.cookieShowLimit){def.cookieShowLimit = 'none';}
    if(!def.cookieExperiation){def.cookieExperiation = 10000;}
    if(def.flag){def.flag = true;} else {def.flag = false;}


    return def; 
})(d);
navigator.sayswho = (function() {
    var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
    if(M &&(tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i)) !== null){M[2] = tem[1];}

    M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N,  navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    return M;
})();       

/*
 * navigator.sayswho[0] === browser name
 * navigator.sayswho[1] === browser version
 */

function createAbie(p) {
    //Get position and set it to lowercase characters
    var pos = p.toLowerCase();
    //Create the abie container div
    abiejs.c = document.createElement('div');
    //Decalre id
    abiejs.c.id = 'abie';
    //Declare position
    abiejs.c.style.position = 'fixed';
    //Declare display
    abiejs.c.style.display = 'block';
    //Set element in document
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(abiejs.c);
    //Create Abie Experience Element (This will animate)
    abiejs.e = document.createElement('div');
    //Declare id
    abiejs.e.id = 'abieExp';
    //Declare position
    abiejs.e.style.position = 'absolute';
    abiejs.e.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    //Set the merit here (this will need to be a condition) !!!!!!!!!!!
    abiejs.e.innerHTML = abiejs.d.content;
    //Append element to container
    abiejs.c.appendChild(abiejs.e);
    //Define the height and width of the merit property
    abiejs.e.height = abiejs.d.height || abiejs.e.offsetHeight;
    abiejs.e.width = abiejs.d.width || abiejs.e.offsetWidth;
    //Set the height and width values
    abiejs.c.style.height = abiejs.e.height + 'px';
    abiejs.c.style.width = abiejs.e.width + 'px';
    abiejs.e.style.height = abiejs.e.height + 'px';
    abiejs.e.style.width = abiejs.e.width + 'px';
    //Run condition to ensure where abie should be
    if(pos.indexOf('t') !== -1){
        abiejs.c.style.top = '0';
        abiejs.e.style.top = (abiejs.e.height * -1) + 'px';
    } else if(pos.indexOf('b') !== -1) {
        abiejs.c.style.bottom = '0';
        abiejs.e.style.bottom = (abiejs.e.height * -1) + 'px';
    } else {
        abiejs.c.style.top = '0';
        abiejs.e.style.top = (abiejs.e.height * -1) + 'px'; 
    }
    if(pos.indexOf('r') !== -1) {
        abiejs.c.style.right = '0';
        abiejs.e.style.right = '0'; 
        abiejs.e.style.textAlign = 'right';
    } else if(pos.indexOf('l') !== -1){
        abiejs.c.style.left = '0';  
        abiejs.e.style.left = '0';
        abiejs.e.style.textAlign = 'left';
    } else {
        abiejs.c.style.right = '0';
        abiejs.e.style.textAlign = 'right';
    }
    abiejs.e.style.background = ((judgeAbie() === true) ? abiejs.d.meritColor : abiejs.d.demeritColor);
}
//Create Cookie
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = '';
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }else {
        expires = "";
    }

    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
//Read Cookie
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {c = c.substring(1,c.length);}
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);}
    }
    return null;
}
//Erase Cookie
function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
//Set property for first loop so danceInAbie.inc can be set
danceInAbie.firstStep = false;
function danceInAbie(pos, h) {
    if(bindAbie.first === true) {return false;}
    //Check if it is first iteration
    if(danceInAbie.firstStep === false) {
        //Update property so danceInAbie.inc isn't updated over and over again
        danceInAbie.firstStep = true;
        //Set danceInAbie.inc to the height of element so it starts animating from current position
        danceInAbie.inc = (h * -1); 
    }
    //If abie's height is less than -1 increment the value
     if(danceInAbie.inc < -1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(pos === 't') {
                abiejs.e.style.top = danceInAbie.inc + 'px';
            } else {
                abiejs.e.style.bottom = danceInAbie.inc + 'px';
            }
            danceInAbie.inc++;
            //danceInAbie.inc = danceInAbie.inc + 2;
            danceInAbie(pos, h);
        }, 20);
        return true;
    } else {
        danceOutAbie.firstStep = false;
        return true;
    }
}
danceOutAbie.firstStep = false;
function danceOutAbie(pos, h) {
    if(bindAbie.first === true) {return false;}
    //Check if it is first iteration
    if(danceOutAbie.firstStep === false) {
        //Update property so danceInAbie.inc isn't updated over and over again
        danceOutAbie.firstStep = true;
        //Set danceInAbie.dec to the height of element so it starts animating from current position
        danceOutAbie.dec = 0;   
    }
    //If abie's height is less than 0 increment the value
    if(danceOutAbie.dec < h) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(pos === 't') {
                abiejs.e.style.top = '-' + danceOutAbie.dec + 'px';
            } else {
                abiejs.e.style.bottom = '-' + danceOutAbie.dec + 'px';
            }
            danceOutAbie.dec++;
            //danceOutAbie.dec = danceOutAbie.dec + 2;
            danceOutAbie(pos, h);
        }, 10);
    } else {
        danceInAbie.firstStep = false;
        return true;
    }
}
//Add Events
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    // avoid memory overhead of new anonymous functions for every event handler that's installed
    // by using local functions
    function listenHandler(e) {
        var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        if (ret === false) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    function attachHandler() {
        // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
        // and make sure the event is passed to the fn also so that works the same too
        var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
        if (ret === false) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
    }
}
function judgeAbie() {
    var v = parseInt(navigator.sayswho[1], 10);
    if(navigator.sayswho[0] === 'Chrome'){
        if(v < 27) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } else if(navigator.sayswho[0] === 'Firefox') {
        if(v < 21) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } else if(navigator.sayswho[0] === 'MSIE') {
        if(v < 9) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } else if(navigator.sayswho[0] === 'Safari') {
        if(v < 6) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } else if(navigator.sayswho[0] === 'Opera') {
        if(v < 12) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } else {
        //I don't know what you have
        return false;
    }
}
//Merit or Demerit
function meriter() {window.location = abiejs.d.mer;}
function demeriter() {window.location = abiejs.d.dmer;}
function abieMeritDemerit() {
    //Get abies judgement
    abieMeritDemerit.judgement = judgeAbie();
    //Decide to merit or demerit
    if(abieMeritDemerit.judgement === true) {
        //If string send user to page
        if(typeof abiejs.d.merit === 'string') {
            return meriter();
        //Else try to run as function
        } else {
            return abiejs.d.merit();
        }   
    } else if(abieMeritDemerit.judgement === false) {
        //If string send user to page
        if(typeof abiejs.d.demerit === 'string') {
            return demeriter();
        //Else try to run as function
        } else {
            return abiejs.d.demerit();
        }
    } else {
        return abiejs.d.dmer(); 
    }
}
function abieRun(pos) {
    abieRun.cookie = readCookie('abiejs');

    if(abieRun.cookie < abiejs.d.cookieShowLimit || abiejs.d.cookie === false) {
        if(pos.indexOf('t') !== -1) {
            //If danceInAbie is complete and returns true then run danceOutAbie
            danceInAbie('t', abiejs.e.height);
            setTimeout(function() {danceOutAbie('t', abiejs.e.height);}, abiejs.d.showTime);
        } else {
            //If danceOutAbie is complete and returns true then run danceInAbie
            danceInAbie('b', abiejs.e.height);
            setTimeout(function() {danceOutAbie('b', abiejs.e.height);}, abiejs.d.showTime);
        }
    }
}

//bind mouseover and onclick events
//Check if mouse is already over element
bindAbie.first = false;
function bindAbie(pos) {
    addEvent(abiejs.c, 'mouseover', function() {
        bindAbie.first = true;
        if(pos.indexOf('t') !== -1) {
            abiejs.e.style.top = 0;
        } else {
            abiejs.e.style.bottom = 0;
        }
    });
    addEvent(abiejs.c, 'mouseout', function() {
        bindAbie.first = true;
        if(pos.indexOf('t') !== -1) {
            abiejs.e.style.top = '-' + abiejs.e.height + 'px';
        } else {
            abiejs.e.style.bottom = '-' + abiejs.e.height + 'px';
        }
    });
    addEvent(abiejs.e, 'click', function() {
        abieMeritDemerit();
    });
}
function abiesFlag(pos) {
    if(abiejs.d.flag === true) {
        if(pos.indexOf('t') !== -1) {
            if(pos.indexOf('r') !== -1) {
                abiejs.e.style.WebkitBorderRadius = '0 0 0 100%';
                abiejs.e.style.MozBorderRadius = '0 0 0 100%';
                abiejs.e.style.borderRadius = '0 0 0 100%';
            } else {
                abiejs.e.style.WebkitBorderRadius = '0 0 100% 0';
                abiejs.e.style.MozBorderRadius = '0 0 100% 0';
                abiejs.e.style.borderRadius = '0 0 100% 0';
            }
        } else {
            if(pos.indexOf('r') !== -1) {
                abiejs.e.style.WebkitBorderRadius = '100% 0 0 0';
                abiejs.e.style.MozBorderRadius = '100% 0 0 0';
                abiejs.e.style.borderRadius = '100% 0 0 0';
            } else {
                abiejs.e.style.WebkitBorderRadius = '0 100% 0 0';
                abiejs.e.style.MozBorderRadius = '0 100% 0 0';
                abiejs.e.style.borderRadius = '0 100% 0 0';
            }
        }
    }
}
//Make Cookie
function abieMakeCookies() {
    //Check if user wants cookie
    if(abiejs.d.cookie === true) {
        var cookieVal = readCookie('abiejs');
        //Create Cookie Expiration
        abieMakeCookies.expry = (abiejs.d.cookieExperiation === 'none' ? 1000 : abiejs.d.cookieExperiation);
        //Check if no cookie exists yet
        if(cookieVal === null) {
            //If there is no cookie then create the first iteration
            createCookie('abiejs',0,abieMakeCookies.expry);
        //If there is a cookie begin incrementing iteration
        } else {
            //If the cookie has no limit then set it a huge number
            if(abiejs.d.cookieShowLimit === 'none') {
                createCookie('abiejs',0,abieMakeCookies.expry);
            } else {
                cookieVal++;
                createCookie('abiejs',cookieVal,abieMakeCookies.expry);
            }
        }
    }
}


createAbie(abiejs.d.position);
bindAbie(abiejs.d.position);
abiesFlag(abiejs.d.position);
abieMakeCookies();
abieRun(abiejs.d.position);
```

}

This is the initiation:

```
abiejs({
merit : function() {
    cornify();
},
demerit : 'http://browsehappy.com/'
```

});

Also, I'm curious if I'm using the proper terminology in the comments. If you look [here](https://github.com/justinboyd/abie.js) you can see more of it's documentation. I would love it if someone could help me out and give me pointers on ways to optimize a pure javascript plugin.

Answer (score 1):

"d", "b", "c", "e" are not good variable names. Use other ones. If you're afraid about the size (and I'll tackle that later), this is gzip's task.
Create local variables instead of accessing "abiejs" every time.

```
// for example, from
abiejs.d...
abiejs.d.style.color = 'red';
abiejs.d...
// to
var d = abiejs.d;
d...
d.style.color = 'red';
d...
```

You're trying to do really too much in there. There's code to add events in all browsers, code to create cookies, etc. I suggest you to take a look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), it uses feature detection instead of just trying to poll the browser.